# Audio equivalent of CurrentImage

Tags: dynamic, neural-networks, sound, input-devices

Unfortunately, there is no `CurrentAudio[]` function yet.

I'm trying to poll for 1 second clips of audio (as fast as possible) from my computer's microphone (and then continuously push them through a neural network I built).

Here's a simplified example of what I've tried:

```
net = NetInitialize @ NetChain[{
    GatedRecurrentLayer[64],
    SequenceLastLayer[],
    LinearLayer[],
    SoftmaxLayer[]},
   "Input" -> {"Varying", 13},
   "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"A", "B", "C"}}]]

inferAudio[] := 
    Module[{clip, enc = Values[AudioLocalMeasurements[#, "MFCC"]] &},
        clip = AudioCapture["Memory", MaxDuration -> 1, 
                    CaptureRunning -> True, SampleRate -> 16000];  
        net @ enc @ clip
]

$stop = False; t1 = Now; Button["Stop", $stop = True]
While[Refresh[$stop =!= True], t1 = Now; c = inferAudio[];
   t2 = Now; Print["Inferred class = ", c, ", delay = ", t2 - t1]]
```

This has a few problems:

1. I'd like to *remove the audio capturing GUI*. There is no need for it and it slows everything down.
2. The code is clunky and the delay between is a bit too much, also the front-end gets crashy.

I initially tried using `ScheduledTask`'s but that was a *terrible idea* (doesn't play well with Dynamics). **Don't run this**, it will crash MMA:

```
recordings = {};
SessionSubmit @ ScheduledTask[
  AppendTo[recordings, AudioCapture[MaxDuration -> 1]], {1, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: A good answer will help anyone who needs to live process audio from an input source.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to kill the GUI:

```
AudioCapture["UseGUI" -> False, MaxDuration -> 1]
```

I found this by digging. You can also use these:

```
Audio`CaptureDump`AudioCaptureHiddenOptions // Options

{"UseGUI" -> True, AudioDevice -> Automatic}
```

And then I can do things like:

```
Table[
 AudioCapture["UseGUI" -> False, MaxDuration -> 1],
 {5}
 ]
```

[image: asdasd]